# Python 3.8: Running External C++ Code: Unable to Import Module

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I am building a C++ DLL file which I am trying to load into Python module.
I am using [the official Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/extending.html). The C++ code (including all the boiler plates) is as follows (a dimple "hello" function):

```
#include <Python.h>

#include <iostream>

PyObject* fft_hello(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
  std::cout << "Insid fft hello" << std::endl;
  return nullptr;
}

static PyMethodDef fft_methods[2] = {
    {"hello", fft_hello, METH_VARARGS, "Runs hello"},
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};

static struct PyModuleDef fft_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "fft",
    "fft module",
    0,
    fft_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_fft(void){
  std::cout << "INITING" << std::endl;
  return PyModule_Create(&fft_module);
}
```

The CMAKE that compiles the module is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(fft)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
link_directories("C:/Users/guyy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/libs")

add_library(fft SHARED fft.cpp )

include_directories("C:/Users/guyy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/include")
```

This yields a `fft.dll` module.

Next, I put this dll in the python file directory and tried importing it:

```
import fft

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

I got the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fft'` error.

So, what am I doing wrong?

- Was the C++ file written wrongly?
- Was the DLL module built wrongly?
- Was the DLL module put in the wrong place?

Comment: I would recommend using Cython over writing a native module yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html or CPython.

[EDITED]
You can also use use distutils. At the root folder create a file named `setup.py` having the following implementation:

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

```
def main():
    setup(name="fft",
          version="1.0.0",
          description="Python interface for the fft C library function",
          author="<your name>",
          author_email="your_email@gmail.com",
          ext_modules=[Extension("fft", ["fft.cpp"])])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Basically, this will create a module called fft%python_version_and_distribution%.pyc which you can add at the root of your folder. This module now can be read by your python file.
You can also run the cmake on this module but it is a little more complex.
I would suggest to check the distutils library for more details.

I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately creating the lib file didn't work. Still I am getting the same error of `ModuleNotFoundError`. I will try working with `CTYPES`, but it looks like an overkill, especially since I am working with C++ and not C.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely require the DLL to be loaded as a "module"?

Using CTYPES is not that complicated. I used it with Python 3.8 and a DLL generated using VC++2010 (this DLL implemented multiple threaded code and worked perfectly).

On the C/C++ code side:
-prefix all your callable functions 'extern "C"', and preferably use standard types for variables and pointers, for example:

```
extern "C" int myTestFunc(int par1, int par2, float *array1)
{
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

On the Python code side:
-import the following modules:
import ctypes
import _ctypes

-in your code/class, load the DLL as:

```
self.lib = ctypes.CDLL('<full_path_to_your_DLL>')
```

-declare the return type of your function (the function name must be the same as in the C code):

```
self.lib.myTestFunc.restype = ctypes.c_int
```

-define the function argument types (below are standard value parameters as well as a pointer to a numpy float array):

```
self.lib.myTestFunc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float32)]
```

-in your code, just invoke the function:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 2
float_array = np.zeros((20, 50),dtype=np.float32)
retval = self.lib.myTestFunc(val1,val2,float_array)
```

-if you need to release the DLL access, you can use the following:

```
_ctypes.dlclose(self.lib._handle)
```